# SQL finding maximum per category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do some practice problems on sql questions because I realized that I'm struggle on them.

I've been playing around with a sample database of mine and I was trying to list out names of restaurants, date inspected and their total score, BUT only the most recent date inspected for each restaurant would be shown.

restaurant has a rid that is a foreign key to inspection and a name. inspection has an rid, idate (date inspected) and the totalscore from an inspection.

How would I get a list of restaurants with their most recent inspection scores and the dates of those inspections?

```
SELECT i.idate, r.name, i.totalscore 
FROM restaurant r 
JOIN inspection i 
ON r.rid = i.rid where
 i.idate = (SELECT i1.idate
                  FROM restaurant r1
                  JOIN inspection i1
                  ON r1.rid = i1.rid
          order by idate desc limit 1
                  );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Group by Restaurant order by date

Answer (score 0):

Much easier then that

```
SELECT
    i.idate, r.name, i.totalscore 
FROM restaurant r 
JOIN inspection i 
ON r.rid = i.rid
where 1
GROUP BY r.name ORDER BY i.idate desc
```

Comment: when i try to do that, the compiler says that i can't group because the columns are not functionally dependent?

Comment: You could try MAX( i.idate ) instead of the order by, hard to do in the head without having a database setup to test it.